# Instagram: Unable to get tagged media object by ID

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-graph-api

I'm currently using this endpoint to pull tagged media on the [Instagram Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/tags/).

From this endpoint I get details on the media and the Media ID.  I also need to be able to get a tagged media object by media ID similar to how I can do it for mentioned media like so:

> {page_id}?fields=mentioned_media.media_id({media_id})

I've tried various different ways to get it to work (just guess work cuz it's not in the documentation) and I need clarification if it's possible to do what I'm trying to do.

Is there a way to get the media object by media ID through the instagram Graph API?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media …?

Comment: Unfortunately the media endpoint doesn't work as far as I can tell for media IDs returned in the user/tags.  was hoping that there was an edge using the page ID same as there is for mentioned_media.media_id to get a tagged media object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the fields that you want for that media. Every node in graph API you can extend if it is available. So, in this case, you will extend with media public fields.

```
{page_id}?fields=mentioned_media.media_id({media_id}){caption, comments,comments_count, like_count, media_type, media_url, owner, timestamp, username, permalink}
```

So in results, you will have media with all fields. Included ID

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `/tags` endpoint, check documentation here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/tags